# TextBox Won't Allow me to enter in a decimal

Tags: c#, xaml

I can Enter Numbers into the text box but it won't allow me to enter decimal values. May I ask why is this?

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SebAmountPer, Mode=Twoway, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>

public decimal? SebAmountPer
{
    get
    {
        return _seb.SEBAmountPer;
    }
    set
    {
        _seb.SEBAmountPer = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged("SebAmountPer");
        OnPropertyChanged("SebTotal");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried both dot and comma?

Comment: Yup! nothing worked besides numbers and letter, But i only want number.

Comment: So I am able to manually put the cursor where I want the decimal to be and enter it in. But If i type it like a regular way it doesn't apply.

Comment: What happens if you type 10 and then place the cursor between the 1 and the 0 and type the decimal separator?

Comment: that works perfectly fine. Calculations are still worked and taking the decimal into consideration. So it actually SHOWS 1.0

Comment: Why do you need that property to be nullable ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A cheap work-around (if you still want to keep the built-in validation and binding to a nullable property), is to add a small `Delay` within the binding. This allows you to actually enter in a 'decimal' point, and after the 'delay' it binds, then evaluates the value as correct.

Example:

```
  <TextBox Text="{Binding SebAmountPer, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, TargetNullValue='', Delay=350}" Height="75" Width="300" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

Comment: it is cheap walk-around, but what if user enter a value after 350?

Comment: Then you make the 350 a 1000 instead. In fact how bout 10000. If a user put in a decimal number into a form and didn't mean to I'm sure they'd rather delete it themselves than have the program delete it before they even know what's happening.

Answer (score 6):

You have a two-way binding to a numeric datatype. The trigger is *property change* which means after every key stroke. Try binding to a string first or change update trigger.

You enter "2." and he updates the binding to 2.0 and converts it back and just steals away your dot ;)

Answer (score 3):

It is binding value validation issue, you just need to set

```
UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus
```

and in the TextBox_PreviewTextInput use 123 456 789 0's answer:

```
private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
   Regex regex = new Regex("^[.][0-9]+$|^[0-9]*[.]{0,1}[0-9]*$");
   e.Handled = !regex.IsMatch((sender as TextBox).Text.Insert((sender as TextBox).SelectionStart,e.Text));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have .NET 4.5 or newer add to the `App.xaml.cs` file `System.Windows.FrameworkCompatibilityPreferences.KeepTextBoxDisplaySynchronizedWithTextProperty = false;` like shown below:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        System.Windows.FrameworkCompatibilityPreferences.KeepTextBoxDisplaySynchronizedWithTextProperty = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a Value Converter to solve this problem.

```
public class DecimalConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            string s_value = value.ToString();
            if (s_value.EndsWith("."))
            {
                return s_value.Replace(".", ".0");
            }
            else if (s_value.Contains(".") && s_value.EndsWith("0"))
            {
                return s_value.Substring(0, s_value.Length - 1);
            }
            return value;
        }
        return null;
    }
}



<TextBox>
    <Binding Path="UnitCost" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Converter="{StaticResource decimalConverter}"/>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: I like this solution. It doesn't need to wait until the focus is lost.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is perfectly correct because the dot - "." standing alone does not have any meaning as a digit.

**Following are valid digits:** 1, 3.3, 23.124, 1., 23.0

**Following are invalid digit:** . -->(i meant dot), .12

so use the following code if you don't want to do that.

```
private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
   Regex regex = new Regex("^[.][0-9]+$|^[0-9]*[.]{0,1}[0-9]*$");
   e.Handled = !regex.IsMatch((sender as TextBox).Text.Insert((sender as TextBox).SelectionStart,e.Text));
}
```

Comment: Definitely Like your method But I want to Retain my MVVM

Comment: Why is `.12` invalid number?

Comment: You could use `Behaviors` to encapsulate it. And you don't want it in the `ViewModel` layer either because it is doing it for the `UI`.

Comment: @Magnus I didn't say it is not invalid in my opinion but the `TextBox` control thinks like it is invalid.

Comment: buddy, you still need to set the UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus. then this would solve the OP's question. Upvote for this solution, simple and logical. Much better than the selected answer, delay 350, what if I enter after 350?

Answer (score 0):

You can change from `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus`. It will allows you insert dot/comma and it validates on cursor box change.

Answer (score 0):

try this one.
I changed the

```
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged
```

to

```
UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus

<TextBox Text="{Binding SebAmountPer, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```